# OpenGL Module using kivy

Tags: android, python, opengl-es, kivy

I am trying to follow this tutorial:

http://digitaloctave.co.uk/pages/kivy/kivy-opengl-tut03.htm

but I think it is a little old, I cant get "from opengl_widget import OpenglWidget" working, it say the module doesn't exist. I think the OpenGL module is to use the "            OpenglWidget:
                width: 200
                height: 200"
in the .kv file.
I can't find information of it anywhere.

What do ya think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just badly written, it's referring to [this file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~oly/python-examples/trunk/view/head:/python-examples/kivy/kivy_widgets_with_opengl/opengl_widget.py) in the example code linked to.

The tutorial is very old though - I haven't looked at it for problems, but be wary of relying on it.